# Is there a way to make specific letters in a string become double?

Tags: java

I have a task to make a method in Java that makes any vowel in the string to repeat itself when its called on the method

example: water would become waateer, phone becomes phoonee

I tried creating a for loop that when a letter in the string is a , e , i , o, or u, it should repeat that letter at the next index

```java
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
  String display = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') {
      str.charAt(i+1) = str.charAt(i);
    }
    display += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return display;
}
```

I keep getting an unexpected type error code and I don't know why this error is happening.

Is there another way to do this? if not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never post code as an image. Also, a *regular expression* makes this trivial. `return str.replaceAll("([aeiou])", "$1$1");`

Comment: Regarding properly-formatted code vs code-as-image: Please see this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which lists many reasons why properly-formatted text is important. Aside from that: Please provide more details regarding your error (such as input string) and anything else for others to help you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - for someone just learning Java (or maybe just learning programming in general), I'm not sure a regular expression would fall into the category of *trivial*...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Perhaps. I learned regular expressions a long time ago. You only have to [avoid two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: The line with str.charAt(i+1) does not compile.  You can add the str.charAt(i) to display, but you cannot set it to a value returned from a method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using `replaceAll` like this:

```java
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("([aeiou])", "$1$1");
}
```

Also your original code was not completely wrong. In the `if`-block you need to add the `char` to the resulting string `display`, then it should work:

```java
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
  String display = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if(str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'i' || str.charAt(i) == 'o' || str.charAt(i) == 'u') {
      display += str.charAt(i);
    }
    display += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return display;
}
```

The result for "water" and "phone" are:

```
waateer
phoonee
```

**EDIT: also include uppercase example**

Regex:

```java
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("([aeiouAEIOU])", "$1$1");
}
```

Non-Regex:

```java
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
  String strLowerCase = str.toLowerCase();
  String display = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (strLowerCase.charAt(i) == 'a'
        || strLowerCase.charAt(i) == 'e'
        || strLowerCase.charAt(i) == 'i'
        || strLowerCase.charAt(i) == 'o'
        || strLowerCase.charAt(i) == 'u') {
      display += str.charAt(i);
    }
    display += str.charAt(i);
  }
  return display;
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works as I want it but it won't work if the word is in capital letters. Do i just add " str.charAt(i) == 'A' " and all the other capital letters to the if expression?

Comment: `if ("aeiou".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i))) > -1)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I included an example where uppercase is also considered